# How to select a folder in Outlook to import to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

The code below is supposed to harvest contacts from a folder within Outlook in to Excel.

The user picks a contacts folder that is not the default contacts folder.

When I run the code using the default contacts folder it works.

When I try to use the PickFolder, it appears to pick up the folder selected as a variable but doesn't pick up any contacts.

I have put ** where it doesn't work.

```
Private Sub OutlookImport_Click()

Dim objOutlook 'Outlook object containing contact information
Dim objNamespace 'Interface definition between Excel and Outlook
Dim colContacts 'Collection of contacts in Outlook for harvesting

Dim objExcel As Worksheet 'Worksheet containing extract of Outlook contacts
Dim i As Integer 'Row counter
Dim objContact 'VCard object within Outlook Contacts

'Prompt user to select folder containing contacts for harvesting

Dim OlApp As New Outlook.Application 'Instance of Microsoft Outlook application
Dim NS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim FolderChosen As Outlook.MAPIFolder 'Folder selected by user

Set NS = OlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set FolderChosen = NS.PickFolder

On Error Resume Next
 Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set objExcel = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Outlook Contacts")

 **
 'Set colContacts = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Items 'using this line works
 Set colContacts = objNamespace.GetFolder(FolderChosen).Items 'using this line doesn't
 **

 'Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 'objExcel.Visible = True
 'Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
 'Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(3)

 'Populate the titles
  objExcel.Cells(1, 1) = "Client Book ID"
  objExcel.Cells(1, 2) = "Contact ID"
  objExcel.Cells(1, 3) = "Title"
  objExcel.Cells(1, 4) = "First Name"
  objExcel.Cells(1, 5) = "Middle Name"
  objExcel.Cells(1, 6) = "Last Name"
  objExcel.Cells(1, 7) = "Suffix"

  objExcel.Cells(1, 8) = "Job Title"
  objExcel.Cells(1, 9) = "Department"
  objExcel.Cells(1, 10) = "CompanyName"

  i = 2

  For Each objContact In colContacts

 ' objExcel.Cells(1, 1) = "Client Book ID"
 'objExcel.Cells(1, 2) = "Contact ID"

  objExcel.Cells(i, 3).Value = objContact.Title
  objExcel.Cells(i, 4).Value = objContact.FirstName
  objExcel.Cells(i, 5).Value = objContact.MiddleName
  objExcel.Cells(i, 6).Value = objContact.LastName
  objExcel.Cells(i, 7).Value = objContact.Suffix

  objExcel.Cells(i, 8).Value = objContact.JobTitle
  objExcel.Cells(i, 9).Value = objContact.Department
  objExcel.Cells(i, 10).Value = objContact.CompanyName

  i = i + 1
  If i > 50 Then Stop - 'just in to make it run quicker

  Next

  End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you think there are Contacts to be found in random folders?  I have never found a Contact outside the Contacts folder.

Comment: @Tony Dallimore I am going to get the users to create and then put their contacts in to a special 'backup folder' (File, New Folder, Contacts) and compare the backup with a firm provided version - we are trying to join together the firm's CRM system to their Outlook Contacts.  I don't want to rely on the users getting the folder name right - whatever I tell them, one or more will call it something slightly different...

Comment: After you run the PickFolder method, are you checking DefaultItemType to ensure that the chosen folder is a Contacts folder?

Answer (score 0):

On Error Resume Next should be followed as closely as possible by On Error GoTo 0. Strive for zero lines between the two.

Set colContacts = FolderChosen.Items (The original might have worked with a GetFolder function?)

To verify FolderChosen is a contacts folder.
If FolderChosen.DefaultItemType = olContactItem

Answer (score 0):

Namespace object does not have GetFolder method.

There is GetFolderFromID, but it takes the folder entry id (string) and (optionally) the store entry id.

Why not simply use FolderChosen.Items?

As a general comment, avoid using "On Error Resume Next". When an error is raised, there is a good reason for that. At the very least, you will be able to see what the error this. Which in your case is a very helpful "Object doesn't support this property or method: 'Namespace.GetFolder' "